# When i click edit button all the buttons are getting clicked with same username

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, express

I'm making a app in which there is option for a user to add a comment and also to delete and modify it but when i click edit button , every button gets called and a edit block shows for every comment created by that user.

I'm running js on backend in node js,mongodb and express js as framework

```
   ...HTML

        <div class='card-body'>
        <%campground.comments.forEach(comment=>{ %>
        <div class='row'>
        <div class='col-md-12'>
        <strong><%=comment.author.username%></strong>
        <span class='float-right'>10 days ago</span>
        <p ><%=comment.text %></p>
        <%if(currentUser){ if(currentUser.username==comment.author.username) { %>
    <form class='cmtForm py-3' action='/campgrounds/<%=campground._id%>/comments/<%=comment.author.username%>/<%=comment._id%>?_method=PUT' method='POST'>
    <textarea class="form-control"  rows="3" name='updateComment'><%=comment.text%></textarea>
     <button  class=' btn btn-success btn-sm m-3 float-right'>
      Update
    </button>
       </form>
         <button  class='editBtn sel btn btn-secondary btn-sm float-right' id='<%=comment._id %>' >Edit</button>
       <form action='/campgrounds/<%=campground._id%>/comments/<%=comment._id%>?_method=DELETE' method='POST'>
    <button  class='btn btn-danger btn-sm mr-2 float-right ' >Delete</button>
       </form>
   </div>
<%}}%>
</div>
     </div>
    <% }); %>
    </div>
```

//..JS//

```
$('.cmtForm').css('display','none');
let status=true;
$('.editBtn').on('click',(event)=>{
    if(status){
        $('.sel').text('cancel');
        $('.cmtForm').css('display','block');
        // $('.cmtForm').addClass('cmtForm form-control show');
        }

    else{
        $('.sel').text('edit');
        $('.cmtForm').css('display','none');
        // $('.cmtForm').removeClass('cmtForm form-control hide');
    }status=!status;
});
```

//Edit button should unhide particular comment section

Comment: You have registered the click event with CSS class name `editBtn`. When you click the button you are changing stuff by CSS class and that's the reason it is changing all.

Comment: [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wvvtWGEBCgyJD-F53B6NhfOu99sqZlUz/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: yeah i see but how to fix that

Comment: using `siblings('.cmtForm)` to selct only siblings of the edit button.

Comment: edit button is not working after adding siblings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comment to the original post, you have the same `class` for all buttons where the `action` is performed and also the same `class` of elements you are changing on the `click` event. This is the reason when `click` action is performed all the comments etc. are changing.

Since every set of elements (comment, edit button, etc.) are enclosed within a `div` you may use `siblings()` function to select the specific elements for changing stuff.

**Here is the demonstration with two rows having similar elements:**

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        console.log("ready");
        $(".b").click(function () {
            $(this).siblings('.h').text("hello");
        });
    });
</script>
<div>
    <label class="h">first</label>
    <button class="b">Edit</button>
</div>
<div>
    <label class="h">second</label>
    <button class="b">Edit</button>
</div>
```

The key part is:

```
// same button element
$(event.target).text('cancel');
// sibling
$(event.target).siblings('.cmtForm').css('display', 'block');
```

Your JS code after modification will look like the following. I removed dynamic elements to make it executable.

```html
<div class='card-body'>
    <div class='row'>
        <div class='col-md-12'>
            <strong>User 1</strong>
            <span class='float-right'>10 days ago</span>
            <p>Comment 1</p>
            <form class='cmtForm py-3'
                action='/campgrounds/<%=campground._id%>/comments/<%=comment.author.username%>/<%=comment._id%>?_method=PUT'
                method='POST'>
                <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" name='updateComment'>Comment 1</textarea>
                <button class=' btn btn-success btn-sm m-3 float-right'>Update</button>
            </form>
            <button class='editBtn sel btn btn-secondary btn-sm float-right' id='<%=comment._id %>'>Edit</button>
            <form action='/campgrounds/<%=campground._id%>/comments/<%=comment._id%>?_method=DELETE' method='POST'>
                <button class='btn btn-danger btn-sm mr-2 float-right '>Delete</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class='row'>
        <div class='col-md-12'>
            <strong>User 2</strong>
            <span class='float-right'>10 days ago</span>
            <p>Comment 2</p>
            <form class='cmtForm py-3'
                action='/campgrounds/<%=campground._id%>/comments/<%=comment.author.username%>/<%=comment._id%>?_method=PUT'
                method='POST'>
                <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" name='updateComment'>Comment 2</textarea>
                <button class=' btn btn-success btn-sm m-3 float-right'>Update</button>
            </form>
            <button class='editBtn sel btn btn-secondary btn-sm float-right' id='<%=comment._id %>'>Edit</button>
            <form action='/campgrounds/<%=campground._id%>/comments/<%=comment._id%>?_method=DELETE' method='POST'>
                <button class='btn btn-danger btn-sm mr-2 float-right '>Delete</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $('.cmtForm').css('display', 'none');
    let status = true;
    $('.editBtn').on('click', (event) => {
        if (status) {
            $(event.target).text('Cancel');
            $(event.target).siblings('.cmtForm').css('display', 'block');
            // $(this).siblings('.cmtForm').addClass('cmtForm form-control show');
        }

        else {
            $(event.target).text('Edit');
            $(event.target).siblings('.cmtForm').css('display', 'none');
            // $(this).siblings('.cmtForm').removeClass('cmtForm form-control hide');
        }
        status = !status;
    });
</script>
```

**Note**: In your code, you are using a global variable `status` to control hide/display comment and changing button label. All rows (items) use the same `status` so you'll have an issue. Instead, you need to maintain status for every row (item).

Comment: after adding .siblings ,all  edit button doesn't respond at all

Comment: @AnuragVerma is there any error? Would you please post your code or create a fiddle that shows the error. I'll take a look. Can you please add `console.log()` statements at the beginning of click handler, inside if, inside else and observe what's happening?

Comment: what to log?? i logged this.target and i found no errors

Comment: I have gone through your HTML elements again. Looks like element having class `cmtForm` is sibling of `Edit` button but the element having class `sel` is not sibling rather it is the same `Edit` button. Please confirm this. If this understanding is correct then use `sibling()` for `cmtForm` and remove `sibling()` for `sel` in the click handler.

Comment: @AnuragVerma I have modified the answer to use `sibling()` for `cmtForm` and same target element for the `sel`, as mentioned in the above comment. Run the snippet to check out.